# SSE/NEON table lookup optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, neon, lookup-tables

i have the following lookup and interpolation code to optimize. (float table with size 128)
It will be used with an Intel compiler on windows, GCC on OSX and GCC with neon OSX.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    const int iIdx = (int)m_fIndex[i];
    const float frac = m_fIndex - iIdx;
    m_fResult[i] = sftable[iIdx].val + sftable[iIdx].val2 * frac;
}
```

i vecorized everything with sse/neon. (the macros convert into sse/neon instructions)

```
VEC_INT iIdx = VEC_FLOAT2INT(m_fIndex);
VEC_FLOAT frac = VEC_SUB(m_fIndex ,VEC_INT2FLOAT(iIdx);
m_fResult[0] = sftable[iIdx[0]].val2;
m_fResult[1] = sftable[iIdx[1]].val2;
m_fResult[2] = sftable[iIdx[2]].val2;
m_fResult[3] = sftable[iIdx[3]].val2;
m_fResult=VEC_MUL( m_fResult,frac);
frac[0] = sftable[iIdx[0]].val1;
frac[1] = sftable[iIdx[1]].val1;
frac[2] = sftable[iIdx[2]].val1;
frac[3] = sftable[iIdx[3]].val1;
m_fResult=VEC_ADD( m_fResult,frac);
```

i think that the table access and move into aligned memory is the real bottleneck here.
I am not good with assembler but there are a lot of unpcklps and mov:

```
10026751  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4270h] 
10026758  movaps      xmm3,xmmword ptr [eax+16640h] 
1002675F  cvttps2dq   xmm5,xmm3 
10026763  cvtdq2ps    xmm4,xmm5 
10026766  movd        edx,xmm5 
1002676A  movdqa      xmm6,xmm5 
1002676E  movdqa      xmm1,xmm5 
10026772  psrldq      xmm6,4 
10026777  movdqa      xmm2,xmm5 
1002677B  movd        ebx,xmm6 
1002677F  subps       xmm3,xmm4 
10026782  psrldq      xmm1,8 
10026787  movd        edi,xmm1 
1002678B  psrldq      xmm2,0Ch 
10026790  movdqa      xmmword ptr [esp+4F40h],xmm5 
10026799  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+edx*8+10CF4h] 
100267A0  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [eax+edx*8+10CF4h] 
100267A9  mov         dword ptr [eax+166B0h],ecx 
100267AF  movd        ecx,xmm2 
100267B3  mov         esi,dword ptr [eax+ebx*8+10CF4h] 
100267BA  movss       xmm4,dword ptr [eax+ebx*8+10CF4h] 
100267C3  mov         dword ptr [eax+166B4h],esi 
100267C9  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax+edi*8+10CF4h] 
100267D0  movss       xmm7,dword ptr [eax+edi*8+10CF4h] 
100267D9  mov         dword ptr [eax+166B8h],edx 
100267DF  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [eax+ecx*8+10CF4h] 
100267E8  unpcklps    xmm0,xmm7 
100267EB  unpcklps    xmm4,xmm1 
100267EE  unpcklps    xmm0,xmm4 
100267F1  mulps       xmm0,xmm3 
100267F4  movaps      xmmword ptr [eax+166B0h],xmm0 
100267FB  mov         ebx,dword ptr [esp+4F40h] 
10026802  mov         edi,dword ptr [esp+4F44h] 
10026809  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+4F48h] 
10026810  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+4F4Ch] 
10026817  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [eax+ebx*8+10CF0h] 
10026820  movss       xmm5,dword ptr [eax+edi*8+10CF0h] 
10026829  movss       xmm3,dword ptr [eax+ecx*8+10CF0h] 
10026832  movss       xmm6,dword ptr [eax+esi*8+10CF0h] 
1002683B  unpcklps    xmm2,xmm3 
1002683E  unpcklps    xmm5,xmm6 
10026841  unpcklps    xmm2,xmm5 
10026844  mulps       xmm2,xmm0 
10026847  movaps      xmmword ptr [eax+166B0h],xmm2
```

When profiling there is not much benefit with the sse version on win.

Do you have any suggestions how to improve ?
Any side effects with neon/gcc to be expected ?

Currently i consider just making the first part vecorized and do the tablereadout and interpolation in a loop, hoping that it will be benefit from compiler optimization.

Comment: Just looking at that, it looks like a very long set of instructions to do the first set of code.

Comment: For doing this, AVX2 (! - Haswell only) has been given the `VGATHER` family of instructions, for lookups in large (in-memory) tables. On Intel, you can do _small_ (tiny) table lookups through shuffles in SSE/AVX but only if your table has no more entries than you can fit into one SSE/AVX regs (so for float, no more than 4/8). ARM NEON can do the same via `VTBL` (and the table might be contained in up to four neon regs, so, again, eight floats).

Comment: Unfortunatly i need maximum compatibility so there is no point for me in optimizing for haswell.

Answer (score 2):

OSX? Then it has nothing to do with NEON.

BTW, NEON cannot handle LUTs this large anyway. (I don't know about SSE for this matter)

Verify first if SSE can handle LUTs of this size, if yes, I suggest using a different compiler since GCC tends to make intrinsucks out of intrinsics.

Comment: well just wanted to make clear that the code will run on various platforms and that it will include neon vector code which i compile on osx.

Answer (score 1):

That’s some of the absolute worst compiler codegen I’ve ever seen (assuming that the optimizer is enabled).  Worth filing a bug against GCC.

Major issues:

- Loading `val` and `val2` for each lookup separately.
- Getting the index for `val` and `val2` into a GPR separately.
- Writing the vector of indices to the stack and then loading them into GPRs.

In order to get compilers to generate better code (one load for each table line), you may need to load each table line as though it were a double, then cast the line to a vector of two floats and swizzle the lines to get homogeneous vectors.  On both NEON and SSE, this should require only four loads and three or four unpacks (much better than the current eight loads + six unpacks).

Getting rid of the superfluous stack traffic may be harder.  Make sure that the optimizer is turned on.  Fixing the multiple-load issue will halve the stack traffic because you’ll only generate each index once, but to get rid of it entirely it might be necessary to write assembly instead of intrinsics (or to use a newer compiler version).

Comment: Also, _change the source_. Blaming the compiler for doing the inevitable (re-loading) because you've not made it clear (enough) that the memory _cannot change_ underneath you isn't fair ...

Comment: @FrankH.: (assuming that the table isn’t marked volatile and `m_fResult` is local, which is almost surely the case) the compiler is allowed to (and should) assume that the table entries will not change underneath it.  That said, yes, the source could be written more cleanly (I suggested how to do this in my answer).

Comment: That's true for `m_fResult` but _NOT_ for `sftable[]` itself.

Comment: @FrankH.: only stores between the loads from `sftable` are to `frac`, which we can see is a local, and `m_fResult`, I assume to be local.  Thus, the compiler may assume that they do not alias `sftable` and therefore that the values in `sftable` do not change during execution of the code sequence unless `sftable` is declared `volatile` (unlikely).

Comment: Thanks so far. i realized that m_fResult was not local so hat was one reason the bad assembly. It is better now but not perfect i think. I'll see whether i can give the compiler more hints about sftable being restricted. The assemlby was created by intelcompiler xe13 btw.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why the compiler creates "funky" code (with lots of re-loads) here is because it must assume, for correctness, that the data in `sftable[]` arrays *may change*. To make the generated code better, restructure it to look like:

```
VEC_INT iIdx = VEC_FLOAT2INT(m_fIndex);
VEC_FLOAT frac = VEC_SUB(m_fIndex ,VEC_INT2FLOAT(iIdx);
VEC_FLOAT fracnew;

// make it explicit that all you want is _four loads_
typeof(*sftable) tbl[4] = {
    sftable[iIdx[0]], sftable[iIdx[1]], sftable[iIdx[2]], sftable[iIdx[3]]
};

m_fResult[0] = tbl[0].val2
m_fResult[1] = tbl[1].val2;
m_fResult[2] = tbl[2].val2;
m_fResult[3] = tbl[3].val2;
fracnew[0] = tbl[0].val1;
fracnew[1] = tbl[1].val1;
fracnew[2] = tbl[2].val1;
fracnew[3] = tbl[3].val1;

m_fResult=VEC_MUL( m_fResult,frac);
m_fResult=VEC_ADD( m_fResult,fracnew);
frac = fracnew;
```

It might make sense (due to the *interleaved* layout of what you have in `sftable[]`) to use intrinsics because both vector float arrays `fResult` and `frac` are quite probably loadable from `tbl[]` with a single instruction (unpack hi/lo in SSE, unzip in Neon). The "main" table lookup isn't vectorizable without the help of something like AVX2's `VGATHER` instruction, but it doesn't have to be more than four loads.

Comment: i'll try around with that. My main error was to use non local memory (m_fResult and m_fIndex). I'll see what comes out if i localize these.